# DNS setup on Centos 6 VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, centos6, domain-registrar

I have a domain registered through namecheap.com, and I have 2 nameservers for my domain (ns1, ns2.domain.com). Both nameservers are being pointed to my VPS IP address. I can access my VPS fine through IP, but not my domain. I am using webmin 1.6, and have my master zone all setup.  Here is the  records file:

```
; domain.com
$TTL 3600
domain.com. IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. email@msn.com. (
            2013040805
            3H
            1H
            1W
            1D )

    ; Name Server
    IN  NS  ns1.domain.com.
    IN  NS  ns2.domain.com.

    ; Mail Exchanger

domain.com.         IN A        x.x.x.x
www         IN CNAME        x.x.x.x

; Resource Record - veryfy the IP where your mails come from(disable if not needed)
; @ IN TXT      "v=spf1 ip4:85.214.123.0/24 -all"

; EOF
server1.domain.com. IN  A   x.x.x.x
ns1.domain.com. IN  A   x.x.x.x
ns2.domain.com. IN  A   x.x.x.x
```

`x.x.x.x` gets replaced with my VPS IP.

If I ping my nameservers, I get `unknown host ns1.domain.com`.

Can anyone give me ideas about what is going on?

Comment: Updated the tags for the post, as the question isn't specific to Centos or to VPS hosting.

Answer (score 1):

The nameservers, as recognized by the Domain Registrars are hosted via your domain registrars.

Ie, you need to have the ns1.domain.com. => IP and ns2.domain.com. => IP on your NS, but you also need to tell your registrar that information as well, through their form/mechanism.

How this works depends on the registrar your domain is registered through.

Edit:

1) does 'whois' for your domain report your VPS's IP addresses as the officially recognized name servers? Are the ns1.xyz.com and ns2.xyz.com pointing to the IP addresses you have a name server running on?

2) you indicate that you have configured webmin to setup the DNS for your VPS. Have you confirmed that this is actually working? Ie, is the name service being hosted on your VPS instances and if so, are the daemons running?

Comment: both nameservers are being pointed to the vps IP currently. I am still getting server not found when I enter my domain in the address bar.

Comment: Editing my answer, since comments don't support good formating.

Answer (score 0):

Look into logfile of DNS server if the zone configuration file gets loaded correctly.
From the quick view i would say there is a mistake in the config file. BIND config files don't use email address with the @.

So my tip is that "email@msn.com." confuses the parser and zone doesn't get loaded. Correct format is "email.msn.com." because the first dot stands for @ in email address.

If the zone is loaded and ok, I advise use of "dig" for debugging.

Comment: How do I view the log files?

Comment: by default logs are in /var/log/bind or /var/log/named

Comment: here is what I am getting with intodns. http://www.intodns.com/dkjensen.com

Comment: If the IP address listed in that page is the name server, then either bind(or whichever name server you are using) is down, not binding to the public ip address, or there is a firewall rule preventing port 53 from hitting your box.